# Trying to make a square UIButton "morph" into a circle with animateKeyframesWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to create an animation that makes the square button turn into a circle when the user presses the button. I tried using UIView.animateWithDuration but if has the same effect as using the key frame animation -> The user taps the button and it just turns into a circle with a border... no 'morphing' into a circle

```
let animate = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    animate.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    animate.layer.borderWidth = 0
    animate.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    animate.center.x = view.frame.size.width / 2.0
    animate.center.y = view.frame.size.width / 2.0
    animate.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 59.0/255.0, green: 89.0/255.0, blue: 152.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    animate.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didPushButton"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(animate)

}


func didPushButton() {

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5.0, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
            self.animate.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            self.animate.layer.borderWidth = 2
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
            self.animate.layer.cornerRadius = 40
            self.animate.layer.borderWidth = 4
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
            self.animate.layer.cornerRadius = 60
            self.animate.layer.borderWidth = 6
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(3, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
            self.animate.layer.cornerRadius = 80
            self.animate.layer.borderWidth = 8
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(4, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
            self.animate.layer.cornerRadius = 100
            self.animate.layer.borderWidth = 10
        })


    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CABasicAnimation will morph the corner radius, and so turn a square into a circle, but it's not the best looking animation  I've ever seen,

```
- (IBAction)animateShape:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGFloat width = sender.frame.size.width;
    CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
    morph.fromValue = @0;
    morph.toValue = @(width/2);
    morph.duration = 0.5;
    [self.button.layer addAnimation:morph forKey:@"morph"];
    sender.layer.cornerRadius = width/2;
}
```

I don't know if there's any way to make this be smoother.

Comment: had to convert it to swift but this seems to work... thank you